# Prove $\big|\langle x,y \rangle\big| \space ≤ \space \lambda \cdot \|x\|^2+\frac{1}{4\lambda} \cdot \|y\|^2$ in an inner product space

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

I want to prove that if I have an inner product space with $\lambda>0,$
then
$$\big|\langle x,y \rangle\big| \space ≤ \space \lambda \cdot \|x\|^2+\frac{1}{4\lambda} \cdot \|y\|^2$$

Where should I begin?

Comment: With the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality. Then think about $(a-b)^2$ for $a,b \in \Bbb{R}$.

Comment: thanks for the help. I was thinking about the Cauchy inequality but never thought of $(a-b)^2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$(\sqrt{\lambda}||x||-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\lambda}}||y||)^2 \ge 0 \iff \lambda||x||^2+\frac{1}{4\lambda} ||y||^2 \ge ||x|| \cdot ||y||$$ but $$ ||x|| \cdot ||y||  \ge |\langle x, y \rangle|$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that by AM-GM inequality we have

$$ \lambda \|x\|^2+(1/4\lambda)\|y\|^2\geq \|x\|\|y\|$$

The desired result now follows from the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.